# ABAQUS: How to connect a shell edge with a shell face?

Tags: finite-element-method, mechanical, abaqus, buckling

I'm performing a buckling analysis of a stiffened aluminium panel. The panel and flatbar stiffener(2) is created as one 3D shell extrusion. The T-stiffener (1) is another 3D shell extrusion.

1. How do I connect the two parts? I have tried the "create interaction"-button, but have no clue how to do it. I guess the load transfer might not work as intended if I connect them wrongly as I'm not very used to shell elements either. Can I connect the shell edge of the T directly to the face of the panel? I'm using Abaqus btw.
2. The partitions of the panel and T-profile are there to simulate HAZ-effects. Are there other options to specify heat affected zones and potentially residual stresses?

All help is highly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: How are the two stiffeners 1 and 2 connected in real life? Is there a connection between 1 and 2 (e.g. welding or brazing) that transfers loads, or is 1 several pieces that are only fixed to the base of the panel?

Comment: The flatbar (1) and the T stiffener (2) are connected to the panel by welding.